# Density of $Y\sim \text{Unif}(0,X)$ where $X\sim \text{Unif}(0,a)$

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability, density-function

As the title says, I'm trying to find the probability density function of $Y\sim \text{Unif}(0,X)$  where $X\sim \text{Unif}(0,a)$ and $a>0$.

Since both variable are uniformly distributed, I know $p_X(x) = \frac{1}{a}$ and that the conditional pdf of $Y$ given $X=x$ is $p_Y(y \mid X=x) = \frac{1}{x}$.

I'm computing
\begin{equation}
p_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  p_X(x) \: p_Y(y \mid X=x) dx = \int_{0}^{a}  \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{x} dx = \frac{1}{a} \int_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{x} dx
\end{equation}

but $\frac{1}{x} $ is not integrable in the interval $[0,a]$.
What am I overlooking?

I'm asking this because for a side project I'm intuitively generating a skewed distribution in $[0,a]$ by doing `random(0,random(0,2))` but was curious to prove what the resulting distribution would analytically be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you could try shifting the distribution to the right, so that $X$ is uniform on $(1,a+1)$ and $Y$ on $(1,X)$. $p_X(x)$ would be the same and $\frac{1}{x}$ would be integrable in $[1,a+1]$.

Comment: Haven't thought of this, I'll give it a try as a different approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the fact that $Y$ is always less than $X$. The conditional density is actually
$$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x} & 0 < y < x <a \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
The marginal density then becomes:
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{a} \int_y^a \frac{1}{x} \: dx = \frac{\log(a) - \log(y)}{a}$$

Comment: Yup, you're right, forgot about the lower extreme which was the one giving me problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$p(y \mid X=x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$ only when $0 < y < x$. So the integral with respect to $x$ should actually be $\int_y^a$ instead of $\int_0^a$.

Comment: oh yes, I knew it was going to be something like this. x must be greater than y